# Import "imports" in eclipse - Java

Tags: java, eclipse, import

I have several java files in a package and all of them have the same import blocks e.g :

```
package org.ezim.core;

import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;

import org.ezim.core.Ezim;
import org.ezim.core.EzimDtxSemantics;
import org.ezim.core.EzimLogger;
import org.ezim.ui.EzimFileOut;
import org.ezim.ui.EzimMain;
```

It looks awful having the same batches of code in each file and i want to refactor it.

I was wondering if its possible to put all these imports in a single java file then use a single line in all the other java files to call them.

Its like the extend function for classes (for variables) , but i want one for the imports.

Thanks

Comment: This isn't possible in Java. Also, a decent IDE would hide these unharmful lines of code for your eyes :)

Comment: I don't think you should be very concerned about this... even in terms of readability.

Answer (score 0):

No. That isn't possible. What is possible is not using imports at all, instead you can use fully qualified class names like

```
org.ezim.core.Ezim ezim = new org.ezim.core.Ezim(); // <-- not import needed.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use * sign to import multiple classes from one package, but thus watch for name clashes.